# @Transient on spring-data-mongodb with Kotlin results in exception during read

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am having a problem in my project with a combination of Kotlin, SpringBoot 2.0, and MongoDB (with Spring Data), with `@Transient`. First of all, here is how I declared my data classes

```
@Document data class Child(@Id val id: String?, val name: String)
@Document data class Parent(@Id val id: String?, val child: Child? = null, val childId: String)
```

I understand there could be a better way to refer to the `Child` from the `Parent`, but the MongoDB is an existing one.

The problem here is, I don't want to persist the `child` property inside `Parent`, so I tried to annotate the property with `kotlin.jvm.Transient`, or `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`, or both. But no combination seems to solve my problem. The problem that I am facing is:

1. When I am using `kotlin.jvm.Transient`, it is loading, but when I save it back, it will persist the `child` property together with it
2. When I am using `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`, it is unable to read with stack trace:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: No property child found on entity class com.example.sample.domain.Parent to bind constructor parameter to!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:250)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(ReactiveMongoTemplate.java:2920)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1.onNext(ObservableToPublisher.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.onNext(AbstractSubscription.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.processResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:203)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryProcessResultsQueue(AbstractSubscription.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription$1.onResult(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl$1$1.onResult(FindIterableImpl.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl$1$1.onResult(FindIterableImpl.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl$1.onResult(FindIterableImpl.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.FindIterableImpl$1.onResult(FindIterableImpl.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.OperationExecutorImpl$1$1.onResult(OperationExecutorImpl.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$3.onResult(FindOperation.java:806)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper$ReferenceCountedReleasingWrappedCallback.onResult(OperationHelper.java:364)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper$2.onResult(CommandOperationHelper.java:405)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:85)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:461)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:379)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:356)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:651)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:618)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:491)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:491)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1000(InternalStreamConnection.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:608)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:593)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:491)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:236)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:266)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$600(NettyStream.java:66)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:325)
    at com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:322)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

3. When I am using both annotations, it is the same result as #1 (obviously), since the application is reading the data before trying to do some logic.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Add a new kotlin constructor and give it the annotation `@PersistenceConstructor`

Comment: I didn't have the parent-child issue, but I did have a Transient and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring the property in the constructor, I believe you need to do the following to apply the annotation to the field that is implicitly created, since Spring Data will be looking at the field's annotations instead of the constructor property's annotations:

```
@get:Transient val child: Child? = null
```

Comment: still the same. in all 3 cases, the error stays the same. :(

`@Document(collection = "parent") data class Parent(@Id val id: String? = null, @field:KotlinTransient @field:SpringTransient val child: Child? = null, val childId: String)`

Comment: @JonathanHandoyo might also try `@get:Transient` instead of `@field`

Comment: still no...
another pattern that i found worked is to declare the "transient" members as `var`s in the body of the `data class`, but it is not intuitive since `.copy(...)` method won't work for the members declared inside class body, and `.equals(...)` won't consider these

Comment: I just checked out what bytecode is generated with some different annotations, and it looks to me that `@get:org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient val child` should work in the constructor. The getter method in the bytecode has the same annotation as a method I explicitly define in the class body with the @Transient annotation.

Answer (score 1):

It could be very annoying, but it is very exact way how spring data works.

Spring data needs a Child object to create a Parent object after loading a Parent data from Mongo, but there is no Child data in Mongo, and the exception is thrown.

So, we should create a Parent object without a Child object first, and then initialize the child field of the Parent object.

I think using @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient and @PersistenceConstructor as following code is the best way to do it.

```
@Document data class Child(@Id val id: String?, val name: String)
@Document data class Parent(@Id val id: String?, @Transient val child: Child? = null, val childId: String) {
  @PersistenceConstructor   
  constructor(id: String, childId: String): this(id = id, childId = childId, child = null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I bumped on this issue and realied that Koltin has its own `@Transient` annotation mapped into `kotlin.jvm.Transient`.

By default, when you write `@Transient`, the imports point to `kotlin.jvm`.

The solution that worked for me it was:

```kotlin
@javax.persistence.Transient val child: Child? = null
```